# Separation between Header and first cell -- In plain UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a table with with Plain style and only one section. I have a implemented `viewForHeaderInSection:` to add a custom view in the section header.

I am  not able to see a separation line between my table section header view and my first 
cell.  [See the attached image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Custom headers and footers do not contain separators below/above them. You'll need to implement the separator yourself in the custom view (or switch to grouped style, which will show the outline of the group above and below it even with a custom header/footer).

Comment: How to switch to grouped style?

Comment: can I remove/decrease the separator height?

Comment: @Imran one of `UITableView` initializers allows you to do just that

Comment: It is grouped, but separator still showing. :(

Answer (score 41):

As Jeremy notes in his answer, iOS doesn't add separators above/below the headers/footers; you can just use a UIView to create a line yourself.

Here's the code to add a standard looking separator view to a header view:

```
CGRect sepFrame = CGRectMake(0, headerView.frame.size.height-1, 320, 1);
seperatorView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:sepFrame] autorelease];
seperatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:224.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
[headerView addSubview:seperatorView];
```

If you're trying to make it look like a normal table view cell, you probably need to add one at the top of the header view too.

Comment: Thanks, useful code snippet. For anyone who is interested, I've placed inside my View class for my custom header in the awakeFromNib() method.

Comment: @Jeff i did the Same.

Answer (score 11):

if you want to give space only between table header and table first row then you can use

In method of `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

```
if(section ==0)
    return 3; // (space u want to give between header and first row);

return 10; //(ur section header height)
```

In method of `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

```
  UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 3)];
  headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];   // use your own design

  return headerView;
```

Answer (score 5):

Add an extra "hidden" row to the section you want to add the separator to by returning `+1` the existing number of rows in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`. Then add the following method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ( indexPath.section == sectionOfHiddenRow && indexPath.row == indexOfHiddenRow )
        return 0.f;
    else
        return [super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

If you want the separator at the top of a section (after a header), `indexOfHiddenRow` will be `0`. If you want it at the bottom of a section (before a footer) it will be `[self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:sectionOfHiddenRow] - 1`.

Now inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, simply return `[UITableViewCell new]` for the hidden row (it won't be displayed, so no need to set a frame or anything). You may need to do some `-1` index adjustments in your `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` methods, but it works (tested in iOS 7), *and* guarantees consistent styling (no need to draw your own "fake" separator—this is  a true system-drawn `UITableView` separator).

Comment: OK, that part with consistent styling convinced me. +1

Comment: seems like a hack but brilliant idea!

Comment: It depends on your visual design and situation, but this didn't work for me because the first row with the separator will scroll off screen under the section header. Usually a separator after the header remains fixed and does not move with the rows.

Answer (score 2):

I've extended UITableViewCell with a couple of separator methods (in Swift). With them I can add separators to headers or remove them from regular cells. I hope it may help some people.

```
public extension UITableViewCell
{
    func addSeparator(y: CGFloat, margin: CGFloat, color: UIColor)
    {
        let sepFrame = CGRectMake(margin, y, self.frame.width - margin, 0.7);
        let seperatorView = UIView(frame: sepFrame);
        seperatorView.backgroundColor = color;
        self.addSubview(seperatorView);
    }

    public func addTopSeparator(tableView: UITableView)
    {
        let margin = tableView.separatorInset.left;

        self.addSeparator(0, margin: margin, color: tableView.separatorColor!);
    }

    public func addBottomSeparator(tableView: UITableView, cellHeight: CGFloat)
    {
        let margin = tableView.separatorInset.left;

        self.addSeparator(cellHeight-2, margin: margin, color: tableView.separatorColor!);
    }

    public func removeSeparator(width: CGFloat)
    {
        self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, width, 0.0, 0.0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a separator between header view and first row :- In view for Header in section delegate method add a subview self.separator //@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *separator;

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return 41; 
}


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

self.headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
self.headerView.backgroundColor = [UIUtils colorForRGBColor:TIMESHEET_HEADERVIEW_COLOR];

self.separator = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"seperator.png"]];
self.separator.frame = CGRectMake(0,40,self.view.frame.size.width,1);
[self.headerView addSubview:self.separator];
return self.headerView;

}
```