# UITableView tableHeaderView's missing separator

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, separator, tableheader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Separation between Header and first cell — In plain UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308151/separation-between-header-and-first-cell-in-plain-uitableview)

When I have no tableHeaderView in tableView than all separator are visible. But if I create a custom tableHeaderView than first cell does not have a separator on top of the cell. Why does my custom tableHeaderView removes first separator? How can I put it back?

Comment: Your first cell will be header now, right?To put separator in header view you have to again put separator where you are creating header.

Comment: If you look at the table than yes, it looks like first cell. But technically it's a tableHeader, just above the first cell. How can I put separator while creating header?

Comment: You can create uiview of height 2px and width of your tableview and provide the background color of your separtator in the end of your header in viewForHeaderInSection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just make a label of height 2 and width 320 at the last of your custom header view and make label background color of your separator color and don't set any text to the lebel, this will work like a separator..

Comment: That was my first thought but I wish there is an easy way to do this simple task. Anyway I'll have to do it myself. Thanks!

Comment: Or you could just use a UIWebView instead, load some empty page in it and give it a background color via CSS. And iframes, add some iframes. Joking aside: if you don't want text, then don't use a UILabel either. That's what UIView is for. ;)

Answer (score 7):

Here's the code to add a standard looking separator view to the bottom of a header view:

```
CGRect sepFrame = CGRectMake(0, headerView.frame.size.height-1, 320, 1);
seperatorView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:sepFrame] autorelease];
seperatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:224.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
[headerView addSubview:seperatorView];
```

If you're trying to make it look like a normal table view cell, you probably need to add one at the top of the header view too.