# when tableView heightForHeaderInSection is used, separator lines are not showing

Tags: ios, uitableview

I was trying to add header views too each section of a table. I noticed that the table view separator lines disappeared when I implemented `tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int)`.

They disappear between header views and the nearest table view cells. Is this the normal behaviour? If it is, how do I get around?

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Have u checked in device?

Comment: yes. Same problem.

Comment: yes this is the normal behaviour. To overcome this you need to create a custom view and leave some space/border at bottom of it. Check this thread. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308151/separation-between-header-and-first-cell-in-plain-uitableview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308151/separation-between-header-and-first-cell-in-plain-uitableview)

Comment: tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Grouped table style.